# Add CSS in a confide laravel web page

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I got some code of Laravel where confide (https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) is used. Now I would like to add CSS in these Web Pages of Laravel.

Can anyone say how can I do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken I'm pretty sure the question the poster was trying to ask is how to style the forms that reside outside of the `app\views`folder. The forms confide uses by default are in the `\vendor\zizaco\confide\src\views` folder.

You can change the default forms and use custom ones by editing the config.php and style them like any other view.

Change this

```
  *\vendor\zizaco\confide\src\config\config.php

'login_form' =>             'confide::login',
'signup_form' =>            'confide::signup',
'forgot_password_form' =>   'confide::forgot_password',
'reset_password_form' =>    'confide::reset_password',
```

To this

```
 *\vendor\zizaco\confide\src\config\config.php

'login_form' =>             'user.login',
'signup_form' =>            'user.register',
'forgot_password_form' =>   'user.password',
'reset_password_form' =>    'user.reset',
```

Comment: Thanks @Terry McCann for your reply. Actually I got this script from someone. The application is partially developed. On the other hand previous developer used **codesleeve** to add CSS and JavaSciprt. I am feeling problem with these.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what confide is or how laravel works.
Confide is a package to manage the authentication process in your website it has nothing to do with the front-end design of your website. It serves the back end operations to authenticate a model.
You must first pass the model through a controller and in to a view.
After that you can use blade templating to present the models and their attributes
and you can use whatever styling you want in your views.
Those are basic principles of the MVC design pattern if you don't understand what I'm trying to explain to you should read the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2)